# Is there some way to have access to Evernote in Gmail in Google Chrome?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-chrome, evernote

Something similar to [Xobni](http://www.xobni.com) would be great, as it adds a permanent sidebar on the right, but their Evernote support is only available for Outlook.

I've tried making a Chrome extension that injects an IFrame with the Evernote interface in it, but Gmail just completely reloads when I do that, regardless of the URL it has.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If still using the old Gmail interface, you can add a widget of Evernote, [like this for example](https://www.technorms.com/563/easily-add-evernote-gadget-to-your-gmail-and-google-calendar).

Keep in mind that gadgets are deprecated, and the "future" is the add-ons for (the new) Gmail.